# change permission mode for new directories and files

Tags: python, linux, unix, chmod

In python 2.7, I save data to a path, e.g. `A/B/C/data.txt`:

```
import os

file_path = 'A/B/C/data.txt'

# create directory A/B/C
dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_path)
if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
    os.makedirs(dirp_name)

# save data to file
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

# change file permission mode to be 0x666
os.chmod(file_path, 0666)
```

The permission mode of file `data.txt` has been changed. But however, this code doesn't change the permission mode of directories `A/B/C` along the path. I want to set permission mode of directories, too.

```
os.chmod('A', 0666)
os.chmod('A/B', 0666)
os.chmod('A/B/C', 0666)
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `os.chmod`.

Comment: If the problem is your default umask, and you want to change it process-wide rather than for this directory, just call umask. If you want files created in this directory to be more permissive than other files created by your process, I don’t think there’s any way to add permissions automatically like that; you have to fchmod the file after opening it.

Comment: Check out documentation for `os.chmod()` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm)

Comment: os.chmod(file, mode) will change the permission mode for that particular file only. But I want to change the permission mode for all directories along the path.

Comment: The question has been edited. Sorry about the imprecise description before.

Comment: `os.makedirs()` allows you to pass in a `mode=` argument in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.mkdir(path[, mode])` allows setting permission mode when we create a directory. The default mode is 0777 (octal). If the directory already exists, OSError is raised.

Solution 1:

```
# RW only permission mode is 0666 in python 2 and 0o666 in python 3
RW_only = 0666

# create directory A/B/C
dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_path)

if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
    os.makedirs(dirp_name, RW_only)

# save data to file
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

# change file permission mode to be 0x666
os.chmod(file_path, RW_only)
```

However, since python 3.7, the `mode` argument no longer affects the file permission bits of newly-created intermediate-level directories, so solution 1 only works for old versions.

This is what I end up with: use process `umask`

Solution 2 [better]:

```
# mkdirs has mode 0777 by default, we get 0666 by masking out 0111
old_umask = os.umask(0111)

# create directory A/B/C
dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_path)

if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
    os.makedirs(dirp_name)

# save data to file (file mode is 0666 by default)
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

# restore old_umask
os.umask(old_umask)
```